# On the deformation theory of associative algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, deformation-quantization

Let us start by recalling the notion of a formal deformation:

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and $A$ be an associative $K$-algebra. Consider a commutative augmented $K$-algebra $R$, with augmentation ideal $R^+$ and assume that $R$ is complete with respect to the $R^+$-adic topology, that is, we have: $R\simeq \varprojlim R/(R^+)^n$. The completed tensor product is defined to be the $R$-module: $A\hat{\otimes}_KR =\varprojlim A\otimes_K R/(R^+)^n$.

Definition:

1. A formal deformation of $A$ to $R$ is an associative $R$-algebra structure $(A\hat{\otimes}_KR,*)$, such that we have an isomorphism of $K$-algebras:
   $A\hat{\otimes}_KR/R^+\rightarrow A$.
2. Two deformations $(A\hat{\otimes}_KR,*)$ and $(A\hat{\otimes}_KR,*')$ are said to be equivalent if there is an isomorphism of $R$-algebras between them such that it reduces to the identity modulo $R^+$.

For any other complete augmented $K$-algebra $S$, together with a continuous map of $K$-algebras $S\rightarrow R$, the formal deformation $(A\hat{\otimes}_KR,*)$ induces a deformation of $A$ over $S$ by pullback. Hence, one may regard the formal deformations of $A$ up to equivalence as a functor from the category of complete augmented $K$-algebras to sets.

Whenever this functor is representable, we call the representing object a universal formal deformation of $A$. In particular, a universal formal deformation of $A$ is a pair given by a complete augmented $K$-algebra $\tilde{R}$, together with a formal deformation of $A$ to $\tilde{R}$, $(A\hat{\otimes}_K\tilde{R},\times)$. This pair satisfies that for every complete augmented $K$-algebra $S$ and every formal deformation $(A\hat{\otimes}_KS,*)$, there is a unique continuous map of $K$-algebras $S\rightarrow \tilde{R}$ such that $(A\hat{\otimes}_KS,*)$ is equivalent to the pullback of $(A\hat{\otimes}_K\tilde{R},\times)$.

My question is the following: What are the uses of this notion? Why is it interesting to have a universal (or versal) deformation of an associative algebra? What can we learn about our initial algebra from a universal deformation?

Also, I would like to know if there is a (modern) account of the relation between the vanishing of the first and third Hochschild cohomology groups of $A$ and the existence of universal formal deformations.

Comment: For instance, every formal deformation of a central simple algebra is again a central simple algebra.  This makes it easier to define sheaves of central simple algebras, i.e., Azumaya algebras: if the geometric fibers of a flat family of associative algebras (of finite rank) are central simple algebras, then also the sheaf of associative algebras is "split" after an \'etale base change.  There are more serious uses of this notion, but this fact explains why there are so many different (equivalent) notions of Azumaya algebra.